# How to display attachment list and Download them on click of List View Button

Tags: apex

On click of List View Button selected Account's Attachment should be displayed on new VF page and there should be a download button as well as download link and checkbox to download  selected(i.e. multiple) attachment as zip file.
Following is my VF page:-

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController" recordSetVar="account" action="{!bumpCases}">
<apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock title="All Attachments">
            <!--<apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!bumpCases}"  value="Download"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>-->
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstAttach}" var="acc">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.BodyLength }"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.CreatedDate}"/>
                 <apex:column >
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewAttach}" value="View" target="_blank">
                     <apex:param id="viewId" name="ViewAttach" value="{!acc.id}"/>
                 </apex:commandLink>
                 <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, acc.id)}" >Download</a>
                 </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton  value="Download Attachment"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

And Controller for above VF page is as follows:-

```
public with sharing class AccountController 
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;
    set<id> ids = new set<id>();
     public string selectedFiles { get; set; }
    public string parentName{get;set;} 
    public Id parentId{get;set;}
    public list<Attachment> lstAttach{get;set;}
    public AccountController (ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }
    public PageReference bumpCases()
    {       
        // Get the selected records (optional, you can use getSelected to obtain ID's and do your own SOQL)
        List<Account> selectedAccounts = (List<Account>) standardController.getSelected();
        for(Account selectedAccount : selectedAccounts)
        {
            ids.add(selectedAccount.id);
        }
        lstAttach = new list<Attachment>([select id, name, BodyLength , CreatedDate, Owner.Name from Attachment where parentid=:ids]);
        // Update records       
        /*PageReference p= new PageReference('/apex/TestChatter');
        p.setRedirect(true);*/
        return null;        
    }

    public PageReference viewAttach()
    {
        ID lid=apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ViewAttach');
        return new Pagereference ('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+lid);


    }

}
```